# MVC pattern: js code that is calling server via ajax part of view or controller?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I know that the webpage that is opened by the user is part of the view. This one is easy, but what about js code calling the server to retrieve data via ajax? Is this part of the controller or still the view?

Can the view request data like this?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, including [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), is a *client-side* technology. Therefore, in the context of MVC, any js script must be part of a *template file*.

Note that a template file is not the *view* (the *V* in *MVC*), but a part of it. The *view* should incorporate both *server-side* components (classes, interfaces, etc) and *client-side* components (html, js, css, images, etc). For example, an instance of a *view* class could read some data from the *domain model* and then load and render a certain template file, injecting the fetched data into it (formatted), in order to be printed on the screen.

So, an ajax object should be defined in a template file. Its *request to the server* is handled either by the controller, **or** by the server-side components of the *view*, **depending on the MVC approach** that you are choosing to implement. Though, the *server response* should always be created by the server-side components of the *view*.